# Cannot remove logback from classpath

Tags: spring-boot, logback

In my application there is a binding of two log files (`org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class`). See below:

```
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/n12017/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.9/logback-classic-1.1.9.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/n12017/.m2/repository/cosine-lsh/cosinelsh/1.0/cosinelsh-1.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
```

Here what I have tried to remove the logback from classpath:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>logback-classic</groupId>
                    <artifactId>ch.qos.logback</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

I have also tried to exclude from related dependency:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

However, I have failed. How can I remove the logback?

Here is the related part in the dependency tree:

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:1.5.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:jar:8.5.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-juli:jar:8.5.11:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.3.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.3.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:jar:1.5.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.3.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:4.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:4.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:4.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.3.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.3.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf:jar:1.5.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:1.5.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:1.5.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:8.5.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:8.5.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:8.5.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.3.4.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.3.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-spring4:jar:2.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-layout-dialect:jar:1.4.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:jar:2.4.7:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.5.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:1.5.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:1.5.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.17:runtime
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:1.5.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.22:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.22:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.22:compile
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got the `groupId` and `artifactId` the wrong way around. The exclusion should be:

```
<exclusion>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
</exclusion>
```

Rather than just excluding `logback-classic`, you may want to exclude `spring-boot-starter-logging` instead:

```
<exclusion>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
</exclusion>
```

This will ensure that various other Logback- and SLF4J-related dependencies that the starter also depends upon are not included.

Comment: Thanks @Andy Wilkinson! When I tried ch.qos.logback I got errors like : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
 at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger....Your second suggestion worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Need to add exclusion to both the spring-boot-starter and spring-boot-starter-web. This will resolve conflict.

Add below dependency in pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

You were very close. You forgot to add the scope provided.

I managed to exclude logback by adding these lines :

```
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>logback-classic</groupId>
                        <artifactId>ch.qos.logback</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
```